# Не получается импортировать по ссылке xml прайс в opencart3

Tags: opencart3.x

Здравствуйте начал делать дипломную работу по интернет магазинам и не разу не выгружал хml прайс скачал модуль Universal Import/Export Pro 3.6.1 там пять шагов по выгрузке прайса но мне пишет ошибку на 3м шаге
прайс https://goldsoveren.com/export/ProJewelry.xml

Warning: No data has been found with given xml node, make sure you set correctly the node name containing your data set

Предупреждение: данные не были найдены с данным узлом xml, убедитесь, что вы правильно установили имя узла, содержащего ваш набор данных

подскажите пожалуйста что нужно нажать на 3м шаге что бы меня пропустило дальше это логин и пароль garamantis.online/admin
garamantison
nO9&%4sFtn

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Я думаю, ля того чтобы пройти 3-й шаг, нужно скормить скрипту именно xml файл, а по ссылке yml. Хоть он и основан на стандарте xml, но неизвестно, как парсит скрипт, скорее всего ищет теги

```
"<xml" и "</xml>".
```

Онлайн xml-валидаторы этот файл не приняли...